# Paypal recurring payment form

Tags: php, paypal

I am using Recurring payment in  my website using two ways (Express checkout and PayPal form), i have implemented by using Express Checkout.

When using Express checkout we can give profile start date, Based on the start date only the payment process will be done.

In the same way can we give the start date to make payment by using PayPal form? I have tried to find a solution for that, But no luck.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to define a variable for `start date` for HTML form. There is no variable for the same. Whenever the payment is made, that will be the start date.

It is possible only using API(Express checkout).